# IntelliJ android errors when compiling a project which includes in a library project

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am developing an android app in IntelliJ which uses a library project.

I have followed the steps advised in the following guide to include the library project in my app project:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html

While developing I am able to access and reference the classes stored in the library project as if the library project was correctly included, and the IDE does not mark any of the library project references as errors (Cannot resolve symbol 'X').

The problem appears when compiling the project, all the references and imports related to the library project are shown as errors (java: cannot find symbol) and (java: package com.name.libraryprojectname does not exist) in the Messages window.

I have looked at the intellij guides, repeated the process, checked other questions in stackoverlow, but I can not find any clue of what is wrong on my project configuration.